# C#: Unicode from a string with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to insert a string into a MySQL database. I can insert it by running the query on the server, but when I try to use my C# source file to insert "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn", I get "IÃ±tÃ«rnÃ¢tiÃ´nÃ lizÃ¦tiÃ¸n". I've tried adding it as a parameter and adding ;charset=utf8 to my connection string, but no luck. The table in the database has utf8 as it's character set. Am I missing something.

This is my code (using a StringBuilder):

```
sqlBuffer.Append(
    string.Format(
        @"INSERT `resources` (id, somefield) 
        VALUES (20004,'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn');");
```

Comment: The same happens with SQL Server, even if I drop the @. I'm totally baffled by this. I've even tried adding specifying the string in escaped unicode format (\uXXXX).

Comment: On SQL Server, is your DB field nvarchar and are you using N'' ("INSERT `resources` (id, somefield) VALUES (20004, N'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn');")?

Comment: It is an nvarchar and I am using N'

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that it's unicode/utf8 with N'' or _utf8'':

```
sqlBuffer.Append(
    string.Format(
        @"INSERT `resources` (id, somefield) 
        VALUES (20004, N'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn');");
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, still a line of garbage when the query is run.

Comment: btw, did you save the .cs file that cointains the text 'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn' with encoding? Check VS, Save as and click the arrow on the save command.

Comment: Are you sure that the data in the DB is incorrect? Does the tool that you use for querying support UTF8?

Comment: Yes, whether I view it in a GUI tool or through a browser, it's the same. I can view the correct data in both when I manually run the query using the same GUI tool.

Comment: The only other thing I can do it just remove that line, but I wanted to demonstrate UTF8 really.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to select the correct culture and provide it to string.Format.
You may want to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx which inspired the example below (WARNING: untested!):

```
using System.Globalization;

// ...

string[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "fr-FR", "de-DE", "es-ES" };    

// this loop will inject your string using various cultures
foreach (string cultureName in cultureNames)
{
   CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

   sqlBuffer.Append(
     string.Format(culture,
       @"INSERT `resources` (id, somefield) 
       VALUES (20004, N'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn');");
}
```

Note that you also need to check your table settings with regard to character set collation.